# Entrys in Rows of Grid default look really unnatural

Tags: maui

In a .NET MAUI App, I wanted to have a Table like UI with Label and Entrys in the second column.

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto, Auto" ColumnDefinitions="150, *, *" Padding="15, 2, 0, 15" ColumnSpacing="10">
                        
    ...
                        
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Value A:" Background="Red"/>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Entry Text="0" Placeholder="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Keyboard="Numeric" TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged" Focused="Entry_Focused"/>
        <Label Text="g"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="0 g" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Value B:" Background="Blue"/>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Entry Text="0" Placeholder="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Keyboard="Numeric" TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged" Focused="Entry_Focused"/>
        <Label Text="g"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="0 g" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    
    ...
</Grid>
```

[image]

I am asking myself why the Entrys get so high by default? The screenshot is from iOS. This really looks terrible to me.

Is there a better way to bring that in a good looking form than setting a HeightRequest for the Entrys? A VerticalAlignment="Center" even also does not have any effect.

Normally, I don't like to set something with absolute numbers like when setting a HeightRequest, but here, I don't know how this could be improved so that it looks naturally.

So, actually the Label "Value A:" should be vertically centered with the "0" of the Entry. Therefore the Entry needs to be move up or down.

What is the preferred way to solve such things?

Comment: use `VerticalTextAlignment`

Comment: Yes, I can do and align to one of the directions, but this does not affect the unnatural Height - just aligns with that. So, is it really like I have to do a HeightRequest for the Entry and then align each of the labels?

Comment: There is no better way, use HeightRequest. To avoid having to do that in every Entry, define a Style that sets it. Similarly, set Label's VerticalTextAlignment using a Style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Entrys in Rows of Grid default look really unnatural

I add `VerticalOptions="Center"` to several for third row:

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto" ColumnDefinitions="150, *, *" Padding="15, 2, 0, 15" ColumnSpacing="20" >
    
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Value A:" BackgroundColor="PaleVioletRed"/>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Entry Text="0" Placeholder="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Keyboard="Numeric" />
        <Label Text="g"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="0 g" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    
    
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Value B:" BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue"  VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" >
        <Entry Text="0" Placeholder="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  Keyboard="Numeric" />
        <Label Text="g" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="0 g" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
    
</Grid>
```

Here is the effect:

[image]

[image]

Wish it can help you.

Comment: Yes this really helps - would you also change TextAlignment to have it right? Or reduce the space between Text and Label „g“ in first column? As you showed with your ruler  it is also out of space. Currently, it doesn’t bother, but maybe I should change it, too?

Comment: As you can see that I only set `VerticalOptions="Center"` currently. But you can try to set TextAlignment in the future.

Comment: Thanks again - so far the VerticalOptions setting had the most impact on what I wanted to achieve :)